WinUI 3 Desktop: Drag and drop file from Explorer to app window
I have the following simple WinUI 3 Desktop app running on Window 11. Dragging a file from the Explorer into the window does not work. Grid_DragOver() is not being called. I just get the red cursor symbol as if drop is not allowed:

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to activate some kind of capabilities?
Strangely it works if I drag a file from the Recent items in the Start section of the Explorer:

But all other places like the Desktop don't work.
MainWindow.xaml:

    <Grid AllowDrop="True" Drop="Grid_Drop" DragOver="Grid_DragOver" Background="LightGray">
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="FileNameTextBlock"
            Text="Drag a file here"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="20"
            FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs:
 using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
 using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
 using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
 using System;
 using System.IO;
 using Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;
 using Windows.Storage;

namespace FileDragDropApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            // Check if the dropped data contains files
            if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
            {
                // Get the file(s) from the DataPackage
                var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
                if (items.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Display the first file's name
                    var storageFile = items[0] as StorageFile;
                    if (storageFile != null)
                    {
                        FileNameTextBlock.Text = $"File: {storageFile.Name}";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void Grid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            // This is not being called
            e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
        }
    }
}

EDIT
I also tested DragEnter. Same result.
<StackPanel AllowDrop="True"  DragEnter="Grid_DragEnter" Background="LightGray">
    <TextBlock
     Text="Drag a file here"
     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
     VerticalAlignment="Center"
     FontSize="20"/>
</StackPanel>

private void Grid_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Grid_DragEnter");
}

Grid_DragEnter is not being called. Clean restart. Nothing.
Tested on:
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 24H2
OS build    26100.2161
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.26100.32.0
Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools 10.0.26100.1742
Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK 1.6.240923002

Your code should work. Are you sure you don't have another layer (Grid, StackPanel, etc) on top of it?

I could reproduce the issue. It seems an issue, I suggest you could post the issue to GitHub for better help.

@AndrewKeepCoding No, just what you see above.

That's weird. I can't repro the issue.

@Jeaninez-MSFT Are you sure that Grid_DragOver is not called?

@AndrewKeepCoding I did set a breakpoint but nothing happens. Only when using files from the Recents section. Are you on Windows 11? I've added my system above.

@Jeaninez-MSFT: I did now: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/10119

@Daniel Yes, I'm on Win11.

Can you share a reproducible test repo on GitHub?

Can you try my drag and drop demo app on GitHub if it works on your side?
(Make sure to clone the "drag-and-drop" branch, not the "main" branch.)
https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/WinUIDemos/tree/drag-and-drop

@AndrewKeepCoding Thank you. I did clone your drag and drop branch, but unfortunately its the same result. Here's a screen recording: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/wovsbjurbppehkwhyvfi9/WinUIDemos-Screenrecording.mp4?rlkey=kf2vce8vb79j9wsvn9swaoxjj&dl=0 Everything from Recent works, but normal files don't... :/

It seems that this is a Windows issue rather than a WinUI issue. This video might help you but make sure you understand what each step does.

Changing EnableLUA in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System to 1, made it work after a restart. I'm using a fresh Windows 11 installation. As an Apple developer, it’s surprising and quite frustrating to have to guide users through registry changes just to enable basic functionality like drag and drop. If anyone has more insights or suggestions on this topic, they would be greatly appreciated. There must be an easier way.

This seems to be a Windows configuration issue, not a WinUI/WinAppSDK issue. According to the comments in the question, the following seems to help:

Enable EnableLUA.
(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System)
Restart Windows.

Since EnableLUA is supposed to be enabled(true/1) by default, group policies or 3rd party apps might have disabled it.

Didn't this actually help? : )
